# How do I have an array in a for loop that actually changes the size of the for loop at each run?

Tags: java

I want my for loop to have the length a changing number. Can i do that?

I havent really tried anything

```
for (int i=0; i < colsAdd[i] ; i++){            
   System.out.print("     0.0");    
}
```

Actually the `colsAdd[0]` is the only size.

Comment: *"I havent really tried anything"* Why not? Also what do you mean by the length? As in the `i < colsAdd[i]` section?

Comment: Do you have an actual use case...something you want to accomplish here?  If you're asking if **colsAdd[i]** can change during the loop...sure it can.  That expression is re-evaluated each time through the loop to determine if the loop should terminate or not.  That test statement can be anything at all. - the fact that most for loops that look like this have a constant "length" that is being tested against that never changes, there's no reason it can't....like in your example.  I'm can't think, however, how the logic you show would ever be practical.  But maybe.

Comment: if **colsAdd[0]** is the only value in the **colsAdd** array, and if its value is anything greater than **0**, you're going to get an **array index out of bounds error** or something like that after the first iteration of your loop, because you'll be trying to address **colsAdd[1]**, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're asking, but it seems like you're wondering what you are allowed to put into the different parts of a for loop, and the order that they run in.

If we change the code you pasted above to match the diagram below, the rules will become apparent.

```
for (initialization; condition; updateCounter){            
   codeInsideLoop    
}
```

[image: for loop flow chart]

Any code can go into those portions of a for loop, they can even be left blank! For instance, the following code is equivalent to a while(true) loop.

```
for (;true;){            
   System.out.print("This will run forever!");    
}
```

Or this for loop increments inside of the loop.

```
for (int i=0; i < 10;){            
   System.out.print("This will print 10 times");  
   i++;
}
```

More in line with your question, this code calls a function each iteration to see if it should continue looping. This function could use any logic to return a boolean value. It will execute at the end of every singe loop regardless.

```
for (int i=0; keepLooping(i); i++){            
   System.out.print("This will print 10 times");  
   i++;
}
```

Now, just because you can do these things does not mean you should! Generally you want to keep the structure of your loops simple so everyone can understand what your goal is.

Comment: Nice!  I +1'd this very nice presentation of what the for statement does.  I'm really curious if this will help the OP though, or if his lack of understanding is much more basic than this.  Either way, someone will likely come across this and be helped by it.

Comment: Thank you! I hope it helps him, but it is hard to tell without more information.